# Ionic3 : I can't open localhost:8100

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I have a problem with **ionic**

I start ionic and i created my project with the command

```
ionic start myProject sidemenu
```

After, I use the command

```
ionic serve
```

**Result :**
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkzWg.png)

but when I want to go to localhost:8100

**it's display this:**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFSoG.png)

I try on Mozilla and IE but it's the same, I can't load the page

(sorry for my english and my message problem in french, I'm french)

Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: Are you behind internet proxy? If so try disabling proxy in internet browser settings temporarily.

Comment: i'm not behind internet proxy, thank anyway

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution :
In the variable PATH, add C:/Windows/System32 and restart your pc, after, open the cmd in your depository and insert the command ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the port to 8080 and see if it will works.

```
ionic serve -l -p 8080
```